# how to get full image from the socket in android?

Tags: android, sockets

hi i transferred an image from server socket to client socket between two android devices. i got the image but it is 0 bytes in size.here is my code

sender:

```
  // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/d.png");
                    byte [] mybytearray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
                    serverStatus.setText("sending...");
                    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    os.flush();
                    client.close();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");

                        }
                    });
```

receiver:

```
 public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerActivity.SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/j.png");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;
            do{
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,current,(mybytearray.length-current));
                if(bytesRead > 0){
                    current +=bytesRead;
                }
            }while(bytesRead > 0);
            bos.write(mybytearray,0,current);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end-start);
            bos.close();
            socket.close();
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                        out.println("Hey Server!");
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
```

is anything wrong in this code? thanks in advance..

Comment: Yes. Aparrently, it does not work.  For about the MILLIONTH TIME, what happens that should not happen, what does not happen that should happen, what gets printed out, what are the results of your own debugging?

Comment: am getting a 0 byte j.png file. but i need to transfer the full image from one device to another device.

Answer (score 1):

> is anything wrong in this code?

You bet.

```
byte [] mybytearray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
```

Here you are assuming (1) that the file's length fits into an `int,` and (2) that the file contents will fit into memory.

```
bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
```

Here you are assuming the read fills the buffer.

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
```

Here you are again assuming (3) that the file contents will fit into memory, and (4) that `filesize` is indeed the correct length of the file. You haven't shown how the receiver can possibly know that.

```
bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
current = bytesRead;
do {
    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        current += bytesRead;
    }
} while (bytesRead > 0);
bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
```

Here you (5) aren't checking the result of the first read and (6) pointlessly reading the entire input into a buffer. You don't need to do that. The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) < 0){
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

It works at both ends, i.e. for sending and receiving, and with any buffer size greater than zero. Use this both for sending the file and receiving it.